# simple_salesforce whitelisted IP authentication doesn't work

Tags: python, salesforce, salesforce-communities, simple-salesforce

I'm using simple-salesforce 1.11.5 to connect to a Salesforce account, my code is exactly what their sample code for whitelisted IP access is:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(password='correctpwd', username='correctuser', organizationId='correctorgid')
```

And I got this error:

```
simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceAuthenticationFailed: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
```

Using the same set of credential, I was able to log in to Salesforce through browser, so I think my IP is whitelisted for sure. Am I missing any configuration step? Really thank you in advance for your insight and suggestions!

Comment: Check your user's login history for errors. Does it say something about missing security token? Do you use normal SF login page or is there a single sign on solution in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I need to leave security_token empty even there isn't one. Also, this account is a sandbox, so I need to provide 'test' as the domain. In the end, this worked:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(password='correctpwd', 
                username='correctuser', 
                organizationId='correctorgid',
                security_token='',
                domain='test')
```

Comment: this fixed things for me. had the domain set to the actual sandbox domain instead of 'test'